# Jax-WS with NTLM authentification

Tags: java, web-services, ntlm

As I read Jax-ws can authenticate with NTLM, but I have a problem;
First of all I create MyAuthenticator java class as describe in java documentation(see: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html).

when I try to connect with soapUI everything is Ok, see request header:

```
Request Headers Value
(Request-Line)  POST /Online/OnlineServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction  "http://CTL.COM/OnlineServices/AcquireTicket"
Host    172.22.2.144:8000
Connection  Keep-Alive
User-Agent  Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Authorization   NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAEAAAACgAKAAWAAAAAYABgD4AAAAGAAYAP4AAAAMAAwAFgEAAAAAAAAiAQAA
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Content-Length  702
```

when I try to connect with java, I got 500 Internal server error, see header:

```
Request Headers Value
(Request-Line)  POST /Online/OnlineServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction  "http://CTL.COM/OnlineServices/AcquireTicket"
Accept  text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Content-Type    text/xml;charset="utf-8"
User-Agent  JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-
Host    172.22.2.144:8000
Connection  keep-alive
Authorization   NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIwAAAD8APwApAAAAAYABgBYAAAAIgAiAF4AAAAMAAwAgAAAAAAAAACgAQAABYKIogoAOTgAAAAP5/lqdc43ElnLlEh5ASEkQlUARgBDAGUAdgBnAGUAbgBpAC4AbwByAG0AbwB0AHMAYQBkAHoAZQBQAEMALQAyADMAMQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABXZ
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Content-Length  443
```

this is my code :

```java
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(domain + "\\kuser","kpass"));
OnlineServicesSoap onlineServicesSoap = new OnlineServices(url,qName).getOnlineServicesSoap();
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); headers.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("text/xml;charset=UTF-8"));
headers.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip, deflate"));
((BindingProvider)onlineServicesSoap).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
   try {
       AcquireTicketResponse acquireTicketResponse = 
       onlineServicesSoap.acquireTicket(acqTicket);
   } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + ex.getCause());
   }
```

I searched a lot and found some posts suggesting to do NTLM authentication but I couldn't to connect.. I don't want to use axis implementation